# @babel/polyfill - is deprecated. Please, use required parts of `core-js` and `regenerator-runtime/runtime` separately

Tags: javascript, npm, visual-studio-code, webpack-dev-server, babel-loader

I am having an issue trying to 'run serve' with a React-App I am working on. I am getting a bunch of error messages but I think are mainly due to this one error -

> @babel/polyfill is deprecated. Please, use required parts of 'core-js' and 'regenerator-runtime/runtime' separately.

### This is a webpack.config.dev.js and webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: { main: './src/index.tsx' },
  mode: 'development',
  externals: {
    react: 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    'react-router': 'ReactRouter',
  },
  target: 'web',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                [
                  '@babel/preset-env',
                  {
                    useBuiltIns: 'entry',
                    corejs: 3,
                  },
                ],
              ],
            },
          },
          { loader: 'ts-loader' },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jsx?)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                [
                  '@babel/preset-env',
                  {
                    useBuiltIns: 'entry',
                    corejs: 3,
                  },
                ],
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(s*)css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      chunksSortMode: 'auto',
      chunks: ['main'],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Any ideas? Thank you!